# PNaCl - pnacl-objcopy is missing, how to build it?

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, clang, clang++, google-nativeclient

Dev env: Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit, pepper_40

Surprisingly in `linux_pnacl` toolchain, `pnacl-objcopy` executable is missing.

```
pnacl-clang++        
pnacl-compress       
pnacl-dis            
pnacl-driver         
pnacl-finalize       
pnacl-freeze         
pnacl-ld             
pnacl-llc            
pnacl-nm             
pnacl-abicheck                
pnacl-ar                   
pnacl-as                  
pnacl-bcanalyzer            
pnacl-bccompress             
pnacl-bcdis             
pnacl-benchmark                
pnacl-clang       
pnacl-opt
pnacl-ranlib
pnacl-readelf
pnacl-strip
pnacl-thaw
pnacl-translate
```

But *-objcopy is available with every other toolchain - `linux_x86_glibc, linux_x86_newlib & linux_arm_newlib.`

```
x86_64-nacl-objcopy --- available in glibc & newlib
arm-nacl-objcopy
```

I am building a portable native client. I can't use *-objcopy tool that come with non-portable toolchains since then I will have to specify architecture `--arch' (x86_32, x86_64, arm, ...) along with -pnacl-allow-native` directive on pnacl-clang++ command line. That will make my app non-portable.

I am looking for pnacl-objcopy which would generate a portable object file and pnacl-clang++ or pnacl-ld would recognize the object file format tool generates.

Does anyone know how to build pnacl-objcopy or is there any other alternative which will give me portable object file?

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: objcopy has a ton of different functionality, much of which is not meaningful for LLVM-format files like those used by PNaCl. Can you be more specific about what use case you need?
pnacl-clang outputs portable object files which are recognized by pnacl-ld. pnacl-finalize converts those linked portable files int the format that can be used in the browser.

Comment: I want to embed a file in. pexe. The only way to achieve this is by using objcopy which will give me .o file then I will link my program with that. o. I referred this page http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967. I have. o ready, but Unfortunately pnacl-finalize doesn't seem to recognize it. How can I embed a text or binary file in pexe? Actual problem is, Native client allows only one .pexe to be distributed, is there anyway i can deploy one .pexe along with few other supporting text files?

Comment: @Derek, please suggest

Comment: @user1 it is usually much simpler to generate C source than to copy the file in using objcopy. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176111/how-to-dump-a-binary-file-as-a-c-c-string-literal for example. It's pretty easy to write your own executable that does this too. BTW, to access data files you can use the URLLoader class. See https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable/cpp/classpp_1_1_u_r_l_loader.

Comment: @binji, I had given thought over it. the problem is - exporting file contents as c hex array increases the executable file size as compared against linking the object file generated by objcopy. there is huge difference.

Comment: @user1 What makes you think that? The object created in this way by objcopy is essentially the same as the object created by compiling a C file with the same data.